# How to add Let's Encrypt to the Java allowed certificates?

Tags: windows-7, java, certificate

I have recently switched to Let's Encrypt Private Beta for several of my domain names, and as a consequence several of my Java programs have stopped working because the certificate is not in the trust store I believe.

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

I have attempted various things, such as going into Windows' Java configuration panel, or adding the root certificates to the cacerts.

How do we export/download a .csr or .p12 file from Let's Encrypt root CA in order to import it to the Java list of certificates, preferably in such a way that all Let's Encrypt secured domains are accepted, not just my domain?

---

I have tried downloading the root certificates at https://letsencrypt.org/certificates/ and adding them to the lists, but to no avail. I have also tried adding `/etc/letsencrypt/live/<my_website>/cert.pem` to the sites but it didn't work. I even tried to add it to the cacerts with keytool using this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138940/import-pem-into-java-key-store No matter what I try, it doesn't work (the same error above appears).

Amongst the googling I've done, I've also found this: https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/will-the-cross-root-cover-trust-by-the-default-list-in-the-jdk-jre/134/13 but was unable to make use of information inside it.

Comment: The Let's Encrypt CA is already in the certificate store since IE trusts it by default.  There is something else going on.

Comment: I have found an answer on my own, but I'm still puzzled on why it wouldn't work. A friend has told me maybe it's because my web server does not deliver the intermediate certificates, but I tried it on https://helloworld.letsencrypt.org/ and it didn't work either.

Comment: Update: According to https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/which-browsers-and-operating-systems-support-lets-encrypt/4394 , DST Root CA X3 was added with versions 7u111+ and 8u101+ on 2016-07-19 therefore it may not be necessary to add the certificates on updated versions of JDK/JRE 7 and 8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:** According to https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/which-browsers-and-operating-systems-support-lets-encrypt/4394 , DST Root CA X3 was added with versions 7u111+ and 8u101+ on 2016-07-19 therefore it may not be necessary to add the certificates on updated versions of JDK/JRE 7 and 8.

---

I have fixed this by importing the Intermediate Certificates (https://letsencrypt.org/certificates/) onto the trust store (using keytool or portecle, see link below). Apparently, adding the *"ISRG Root X1"* root certificate did not work on its own, adding all of the certificates caused the errors to go away.

---

In order to achieve this I have followed this question's most popular answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11617210/how-to-properly-import-a-selfsigned-certificate-into-java-keystore-that-is-avail but it should also work with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138940/import-pem-into-java-key-store

Comment: Do you have simple instructions for this? I did `sudo keytool -trustcacerts -keystore /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt -importcert -file ~/Downloads/isrgrootx1.pem` for the certs here https://letsencrypt.org/certificates/. Got errors on the two later: `keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Certificate not imported, alias <mykey> already exists`, but I notice now that I get that on the root as well if I try to add it iagain.

Comment: I didn't go this route so if I were doing this over again I'd follow the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138940/import-pem-into-java-key-store , but looking at your command, where is the -alias argument?

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I was missing the -alias argument. And then the .pem files didn't work with keytool but I could use the .der so problem solved.

Answer (score 5):

Download all the certificates on https://letsencrypt.org/certificates/ (choose the **der** format) and add them one by one with this kind of command (example for `letsencryptauthorityx1.der`):

```
keytool -import -keystore PATH_TO_JDK\jre\lib\security\cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt -trustcacerts -alias letsencryptauthorityx1 -file PATH_TO_DOWNLOADS\letsencryptauthorityx1.der
```